# tensorflow 2.x - tf.cond Lengths of branch outputs of cond must match

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

See the following tensorflow 2.x code, in graph mode. The `du` gradient will be `None`, as `u` does not depend on `x`. In my application, `du` is sometimes `None`, sometimes a tensor. So I want `du` to be `0.0` instead of `None` when needed. My code does not work, see the error below. How to properly implement this in tensorflow graph mode?

```
x = tf.Variable(1.0)
y = tf.Variable(1.0)

@tf.function
def func():
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        u = y + 3.0

    du = tape.gradient(u, x)
    du = tf.cond(tf.cast(du == None, tf.bool), lambda: 0.0, lambda: du)
    return du

print(func())
```

The error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/tmp/ipykernel_5106/913668970.py", line 10, in func  *
        du = tf.cond(tf.cast(du == None, tf.bool), lambda: 0.0, lambda: du)
...
    ValueError: Lengths of branch outputs of cond must match.
    len(graphs[0].outputs): 1
    len(graphs[1].outputs): 0
```

---

Note the following works perfectly (`du` is not None, because `u = y + 3.0 + x`):

```
x = tf.Variable(1.0)
y = tf.Variable(1.0)

@tf.function
def func():
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        u = y + 3.0 + x

    du = tape.gradient(u, x)
    du = tf.cond(tf.cast(du == None, tf.bool), lambda: 0.0, lambda: du)
    return du

print(func())
```

output: `tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `zero_if_none` function does the trick:

```
x = tf.Variable(1.0)
y = tf.Variable(1.0)

@tf.function
def zero_if_none(du):
    if du == None:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return du

@tf.function
def func():
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        u = y + 3.0

    du = tape.gradient(u, x)
    # du = tf.cond(tf.cast(du == None, tf.bool), lambda: 0.0, lambda: 0.0 + du)
    du = zero_if_none(du)

    return du

print(func())
```